# ReadTimeout in cqlsh console of cassandra

Tags: cassandra, timeout

I have a three node cassandra 3.11.4 cluster with replication factor 3, and the size of keyspace is less than 7G, I want to run a query with allow filtering but I got ReadTimeout exception, I set the consistency level to local_one and increase value of read_request_timeout_in_ms to 20 sec in all three nodes and restart the nodes but I got the ReadTimeout error earlier than 20 seconds, nearly after 10 seconds, I also set timeout in cqlsh using cqlsh --request-timeout 120 but it doesn't work too, can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

In cassandra.yaml file you can also set some parameters regarding read timeout. In the past I changed them and got rid of the timeout error.

Examples:
read_request_timeout_in_ms (default 5000 msec)
request_timeout_in_ms (default 10000 msec)

https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/configuration/configCassandra_yaml.html

Note that it is recommended not to use allow filtering since it will start reading data from you whole cluster.